# Puppeteer not working for a specific website in app engine but not on my local system

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, puppeteer

https://partner.zerodha.net/

I am trying to get cookies for this page on app engine standard environment using pupeteer. Other pages are working fine but not this. One thing I notificed is that the code works in my macbook pro and i am getting cookies . This is driving me nuts for a week now.

```
const USER_ID_SELECTOR='#userid';
const PASSWORD_SELECTOR='#password';
const KITE_LOGIN_SELECTOR='#container > div > div > div.login-form > form > div.actions > button';
const TWO_FA_SELECTOR='#pin';
const TWO_FA_LOGIN='#container > div > div > div.login-form > form > div.actions > button';
const LOGIN_SELECTOR = 'body > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > a';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://partner.zerodha.net',{
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  await page.click(LOGIN_SELECTOR);
  await page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  console.log(page.url());
  console.log('page loaded');
  await page.click(USER_ID_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(username);
  await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(password);
  await page.click(KITE_LOGIN_SELECTOR);
  await page.waitForSelector(TWO_FA_SELECTOR);
  console.log('waiting for 2 factor selector');
  await page.click(TWO_FA_SELECTOR);
  await page.keyboard.type(twoFA);
  await page.click(TWO_FA_LOGIN);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  console.log('cookie page reached');
  const cookieResponse = await page.cookies();
  const cookie = `${cookieResponse[0].name}=${cookieResponse[0].value}`;
  browser.close();
```

Puppeteer version
"puppeteer": "^10.1.0",

Comment: can you show what error are you getting ?

Comment: timeout 3000 second for LOGIN_SELECTOR

Comment: can you update the puppeteer version and check issue persist or resolved?

Comment: yes. let me check

Comment: update: @DivyaniYadav Did not work. But I tried running in compute engine and its works fine.

Comment: I need it running in app engine

Comment: Is your issue resolved yet? If no, then have a look at this [GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1036#issuecomment-410536172), follow the steps as mentioned and let me know if it worked.